# Create a Mercurial repository out of an existing directory in another repository?

Tags: mercurial

I want to split up one of my Mercurial repositories into two separate repositories.  In particular, I want to take a directory sitting at the root level of the repository and convert that into it's own repository.

My initial thought on how to do this is to tell the existing repository to forget about that particular directory, add the directory to .hgignore, and then convert the directory into it's own repository.  However, I'd like to preserve the history of the directory in the new repository.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Convert extension](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/ConvertExtension) with --filemap option will do it. See [Converting from Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial) part

> It's also useful to filter Mercurial repositories to get subsets of an
>   existing one. For example to transform a subdirectory subfoo of a
>   repository foo into a repository with its own life (while keeping its
>   full history), do the following:

```
$ echo include subfoo > /tmp/myfilemap
$ echo rename subfoo . >> /tmp/myfilemap
$ hg convert --filemap /tmp/myfilemap /path/to/repo/foo /tmp/mysubfoo-repo
```